# How to add height and width to Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a jquery script i found online for my ticketing software. It adds the functionality of adding videos to a WIKI. the problem is it does not set a height or width to the video is it possible that it can be done with this code?

```
if ($('#idEditArticle')) {
    var videos = $('a[href$=".m4v"], a[href$=".mp4"]');
    $.each(videos, function(i, video) {
        $(video).parent().prepend('<video src="'+$(video).attr('href')+'" controls></video><br/>');
    });
}
```

here is the output in html

```
<p>
<a border="0" class="fb_attachment" href="default.asp?pg=pgDownload&amp;pgType=pgWikiAttachment&amp;ixAttachment=136818&amp;sFileName=Paragon%20Invoice%203.mp4" rel="nofollow" title="">Paragon Invoice 3.mp4</a></p>
```

Even if its possible to manually add it to the html. I can't add inline css to the elements. I tried wrapping it into a div but it won't take an inline style it just deletes it upon submission.

Can i add a height and width to the jquery code to automatically set the height and width of videos.

Comment: A video element without `width` or `height` will just display as the size of the video. Of course you can add `height` and `width` to that using styles. However, your output _does not match_ your script. Your output is simply the `input` without the script actually applied.

Comment: What "does not accept div styles" lol?

Comment: I should be more clear one second

Comment: It is no clearer now, as inline styles on a div should work. However, _there is no divs in your in or output_ and _your output does not match what your script does_

Comment: that's exactly the problem! i have no idea how the hell this works but it works. The video plays but its huge because of the video default height and width. The jquery does not match the Output and i don't know how to do anything because i don't even understand to begin with :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Please note I am using `max-width` but any style will do.

```
if ($('#idEditArticle')) {
    var videos = $('a[href$=".m4v"], a[href$=".mp4"]');
    $.each(videos, function(i, video) {
        // Added a style attribute here.
        $(video).parent().prepend('<video src="'+$(video).attr('href')+'" controls style="max-width: 100%;"></video><br/>');
    });
}
```

A clearer (from a coding perspective) way would be:

```
if ($('#idEditArticle')) {
    // Search for all matching elements. Returns an array of jQuery objects.
    var videos = $('a[href$=".m4v"], a[href$=".mp4"]');
    // Simply use the array.each to iterate over the preceeding array.
    videos.each(function(){
        // now create a link, video and source element
        var link   = $(this);
        var video  = $('<video />');
        var source = $('<source />').attr('src', link.attr('href'));
        // append the element correctly to create a tree
        video.append(source);
        // Heres where you apply multiple style elements
        video.css({'max-width':'100%'});
        // prepend the tree to the desired location
        link.parent().prepend(video);
    });
}
```

The implementation works (might have had an extra space in `< source />` - its supposed to be `<source />`:

```js
        // Search for all matching elements. Returns an array of jQuery objects.
        var videos = $('a[href$=".m4v"], a[href$=".mp4"]');
        // Simply use the array.each to iterate over the preceeding array.
        videos.each(function(){
            // now create a link, video and source element
            var link   = $(this);
            var video  = $('<video />');
            var source = $('<source />').attr('src', link.attr('href'));
            // append the element correctly to create a tree
            video.append(source);
            video.css('max-width','100%');
            // prepend the tree to the desired location
            link.parent().prepend(video);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="test.mp4">Test</a>
```

Comment: hey buddy thanks the top one worked the bottom one did not, the video doesn't show up anymore if i use the bottom.

Comment: The weird thing is now the video is small as hell with the top function

Comment: Yeah well, that s `max-width` for ya. I can't really say more, this is now a styling issue. I fixed the second implementation as well, was a misquoted `<source />` element. The snippet proves it.